# Eclipse Android XML files freezing

Tags: eclipse

I have a major problem with Eclipse.  Well, I have 100 problems with Eclipse (because it is a garbage IDE), but let me just clarify this one.  I am doing Android development.  Every time I open, close, or save an XML file, Eclipse freezes for 5 minutes (and hogs the majority of my system's CPU).  This happens for every XML file in my android project.  And this happens all day long.  Needless to say that I have lost countless hours of development time because Eclipse Foundation cannot make a solid IDE.  In fact I think Google should dump Eclipse Foundation in the garbage and create their own dedicated IDE for Android.....  but I digress.

I have already disabled indexing for my workspace directories on Windows.  And I have read the countless posts on StackOverflow about how to optimize the Eclipse.ini file.  I have tried it all.  I have reinstalled Eclipse multiple times.  I have a Win 7 64bit machine running on an i7 processor with 8GB of RAM!!  I don't know what else to do besides switch to a Linux-based distro or buy a new laptop.  Can somebody give me a professional advice?

Thank you,
Igor

**UPDATE**
My wishes came true with Android Studio, and I use that now as my sole IDE.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? Juno, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I have Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be the same issue as [#385272](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272) reported in the Eclipse bugtracker, where many people have reported performance problems in Eclipse Juno when switching between editors, with most of the people pointing to the XML editor as the worst offender, with some specifically mentioning Android. In that thread, one user suggested a [workaround](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272#c184):

> Switching in window->preferences to "Classic theme" and "Disable animations" bring is to an almost acceptable speed - i can work now.

Beyond that, though, it seems that some fixes for this issue and others are available as a patch, being tracked as issue [#394588](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394588). Apparently, installing the patch fixed the problem for at least [one user](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272#c222):

> Since I installed the  Eclipse UI Juno SR1 Optimizations ([comment #212](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272#c212)), switching between tabs is much better.
>   Thanks.

You can follow the installation instructions in [comment #8](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394588#c8) in the patch thread and see if it helps anything for you.

**Update (12-13-12):**

The aforementioned patches are now available to be installed via the Eclipse update manager. They can be found on the Eclipse 4.2 update site (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2) under the category "Juno SR1 Patches". More details can be found on the Eclipse wiki [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Juno_Performance_Investigation).

Comment: I appreciate it.  I really didn't think that using an IDE sensibly would require following patches and bug fixes.  It's like "if it ain't broken, don't fix it."  But obviously here, Eclipse is seriously broken!!!  And besides, I wasn't using animations in the first place.

Comment: @Igor In case you're interested, the patches have been released and can now be installed via the Eclipse update manager (see my updated answer).

Comment: I just installed them.  We'll see how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: Guess what: eclipse now won't start because of that metadata/.log error.  Jesus, aren't they ever going to fix this problem??  It wastes our developers time!

Comment: Were these performance fixes incorporated in newer versions of Eclipse? I'm experiencing something like this in Kepler with the Android layout editor, and I literally have to use a separate text editor if I want to work with layout files.

Comment: @Karakuri, yes the fixes for this problem are included in the Kepler builds. Are you able to open non-Android XML files okay? If so, it's likely a separate issue, whether with Eclipse itself or the Android plugin.

Comment: @hopper I can open other files just fine. In fact, I can open a lot of my Android XML files (including layout files), but a small handful of Android XML layout files cause Eclipse to freeze. I have not yet discerned any cause...